# Finding OpenGL image plane coordinates

Tags: opengl, 3d, camera, perspective

I am trying to implement a raytracer that uses an arbitrary camera position and perspective projection. I have the camera position, the look at position, the angle of field of view, but I cannot figure out the direction I have to shoot the rays so that each ray corresponds to a pixel. If I could find a way to find the coordinates of the image plane, or the direction vectors the rays should have, it would be downhill from there. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would do the following: imagine that there is a rectangular grid just in front of your eye. The grid is defined by one point (the (0;0) point of the grid) and two (three dimensional) base vectors (x,y); with this you can calculate a ray as (origin + Xcoordinate * x + Ycoordinate * y) - eye. By adjusting the distance between your eye point, and origin; or by adjusting the length of the base vectors you could get the desired angle of view.

Comment: Thank you for an answer that really makes sense. But I guess I have found a solution that is easier to implement: http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/selection.htm (the pick ray)
Of course, I will use pixel coordinates instead of mouse coordinates.